# Deploy app to Heroku through Git (non-fast-forward)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, localhost, staging

I had set remote access to Heroku, so I could deploy my app to Heroku with the commang
`git push staging master`. I don't know what crashed, but now when I run the command from the previous sentence, so I get the error:

```
To git@heroku.com:mystagingapp.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:staging-app.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't want nothing merge, I wanna just delpoy my actual version of app from localhost to Heroku. What is the easiest way to do it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure you just want to push what you've got checked in locally to heroku, you could do `git push -f staging master`. That can result in deleting commits from the remote repo, so use it with care.